# Json+PHP - Mostrar texto si el valor es true

Tags: php, html, json

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://crackwatch.com/api.php"); // add your url which contains json file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
//print_R($json);
$count=count($json);
echo'<table><th>Juego</th><th>Protección</th>';
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
  echo'<tr><td>'.$json[$i]['post_title'].'</td><td>'.$json[$i]['cracked'].'</td></tr>';


}
echo'</table>';

?>
```

En el valor del json en una parte indica **"cracked": false,** o **"cracked": true,**

cuando imprimo el resultado me figura 1 y en lo que dice false no figura nada, yo quiero mostrar un texto que diga **ya crackeado** o **no crackeado**

[image: DEJO ESTA IMAGEN DE MUESTRA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo sería cambiar:

```
echo'<tr><td>'.$json[$i]['post_title'].'</td><td>'.($json[$i]['cracked'] == 1? 'no ': '').'crackeado</td></tr>';
```

Comment: @Nomak, en caso el tipo de variable es un boolean, lo comparas ~ `$json[$i]['cracked'] == false`